# Multiple References For A Job

Tags: references

Do companies ask for multiple references because they want to speak to several people who know the applicant or because they're anticipating not being able to reach some of the references and want backups?

Comment: At what stage in the process did they ask you for multiple references? Is this for a security clearance or a really important job like a CEO or a VP position? Are you sure you're not talking to a 3rd party recruiter instead of an actual company? Sometimes, some 3rd party recruiters masquerade as employers so they can collect the contact information and the organizational chart of people in a particular company they're targeting. It also gives them a fake reason to call (without getting hung up on).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do companies ask for multiple references because they want to speak to
>   several people who know the applicant or because they're anticipating
>   not being able to reach some of the references and want backups?

Both. When I checked references, I always asked for at least three.

I wanted more than one, because I always wanted more than one point of view. Preferably they are from different jobs, if possible.

Inevitably, I would have trouble getting in contact with a reference. Sometimes because the reference was too far in the past.

Comment: Did you ever ask the candidate for additional references if you couldn’t reach one or more of the references provided?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’ll have to keep that in mind in case the contact information I have is too old and has changed.

Answer (score 0):

They want to know how the applicant's previous co-workers/bosses view them. The more information the better, simple as that.